# Como manter sessão PHP durante upload longo

Tags: php, jquery, session, upload

Olá, tenho um sistema básico de autenticação usando session pra um sistema de file-upload
Porém, quando algum usuário com internet lenta coloca muitos arquivos na fila de upload (10 ou mais arquivos), sendo que cada arquivo demoraria 1 hora pra ser upado, ele acaba sendo desconectado depois de 1 ou mais horas

Eu já tentei resolver esse problema usando as diretivas
**session.gc_maxlifetime

session.cookie_lifetime**
E também a função **session_set_cookie_params**.

Porém, mesmo usando elas, o usuário continua sendo deslogado após 1 hora ou um pouco mais e nunca conseguindo completar o restante dos seus uploads
(Já que a sessão é destruída por inatividade na página, apesar dele continuar upando o arquivo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o session_cache_expire() ele aumenta ou diminui o tempo de expiração de uma sessão. Recebe como parâmetro o tempo em minutos para expiração da sessão. Precisamos declarar essa função antes de session_start(). Veja um exemplo dessa função:

```
<?php
//INICIO A SESSÃO COM UM TEMPO DE EXPIRAÇÃO DE 10 MINUTOS
session_cache_expire(10);
session_start();
?>
```

Você também pode usar como alternativa:

Criar um Cookie onde você tem que usar os Cookie para manter, caso as sessions estejam apagadas, então você busca nos cookies e resete as sessions.